# React + Express routing issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router-v4

I have one react application created using `create-react-app` command.

For example I have the following routing in my react application.

```
/Home
/About
/Profile/:id
```

Each routing is working perfectly in `create-react-app`.

In my node application I have written all api for this application and are available using at `myServer/api/v1/`. On other route I'm simply returning `build/index.html` which is my build for react application.

Here is `server.js` code snippet

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/build'));

/* route path : 'api/v1/' */
app.use(require('./server/v1/routes')); 

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/build/index.html'));
});
```

This is my `server/v1/routes/index.js` file

```
 var express = require('express');
 var router = express.Router();

 router.use('/api/v1/', require('./../api'));

 module.exports = router;
```

This is my `api/index.js` file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var path = require('path');

import generalRouter from './controllers/general/router';
import profileRouter from './controllers/prifile/router';

//Login, forget password, reset password
router.use('/', generalRouter); 
router.use('/profile', profileRouter);

module.exports = router;
```

each router file contains relative `get/post/put/delete` method for my application.

React routing :

```
 <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact={true} path='/' component={Home}/>
            <Route path='/About' component={About}/>
            <Route path='/ContactUs' component={ContactUs}/>
            ....
            <Route path='/Profile/:id?' component={Profile}/>
            <Route path='/VerifyAccount/:verifyLink?' component={VerifyAccount}/>
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
```

All my routing are working perfectly except routes with parameters in above example `Profile/:id` and  is not working. Same for all other routes (`/VerifyAccount/:verifyLink?`) that are using parameters in react routing in my application. Its working in `create-react-app` but not with my node server. Even if I comment out my `api` routes.

Comment: Could you share your ./server/v1/routes.js?

Comment: @SamiHult please see update

Comment: I have also tried commenting out api routings and just using react build's index.html but no luck.

Comment: Can you share your react-router code

Comment: I guess its a typo while posting the question but please re-check for the router name your are providing to `/profile`(in the question, you are importing `profileRouter` but providing `locumRouter`) and can you also please add the file for profile router.?

Comment: @RaghavGarg yes it was typo in my question. Profile router contains get method with for getting profile info. But it shouldn't be conflict with react as api are called from api/v1/profile.

Comment: are you getting any errors(please share), if not then what page are you seeing? Please explain `Profile/:id route is not working` behavior in detail What is it showing when you trigger this route? Please try adding a route in the end like `<Route path='*' component={FourOFour}/>`, it may give you some insight about the actual problem.

Comment: Its showing blank page. One more thing when i add extra '/' behind each route its not working in node server but works in `react-create-app` 's `react-scripts start` but not with node @RaghavGarg

Comment: Its not going in 404 but when Im using path like Path1/ or Path1/Path2 its not working with react and node